# How to boot up from usb?

Tags: boot, usb

HI how can i boot up a usb.I already install ubuntu iso. and create a bootable usb using pendrive..i restarted my computer but the usb wont boot up.What should i do.Please answer me AS SOON AS POSSIBLE ..thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might have to configure your bios to boot from usb first.
1. Go to bios (by pressing Del or F2 at startup).
2. Go to "BOOT" and change the order so the usb is on top.
3. Save configuration and try again.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Also look for 'Boot Device Selection' (press F12 or something) - then select the entry beginning with the manufacturer of the USB drive. If you want to actually USE Ubuntu on the USB, you should install to the USB from another image on a CD or DVD, or another USB. This means it will save your changes, data etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, just restart your system and press continuously delete for desktops or F2 for laptop, it might be different in your case according to your vendor..

then change the boot priority , and set first boot priority to Usb. thats all

after booting up it with USB choose try ubuntu for trying ubuntu for first look or install it on HDD by clicking Install Ubuntu..